# How to install FFMPEG to Ubuntu 14.04 from Github using Composer?

Tags: php, json, ubuntu, ffmpeg, composer-php

Recently i installed composer and Ratchet. Everything worked fine but now i need to install FFMPEG through [Github](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#basic-usage). Json and Lock files were already been created and i just upgraded it. I have FFMPEG in .lock file and in JSON file (as it was told). So now, when i'm running

```
./composer.phar install
```

it is not installing and telling me

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

What is wrong with this installer?

Comment: How exactly did you try to "install" PHP-FFMpeg? Did you add it to your main project's `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files, e.g. via `composer require` in that directory? Or did you download the PHP-FFMPeg repository from GitHub manually?

Comment: The title is misleading , anyway if you need ffmpeg , try this installer : https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer
But if You need **php-ffmpeg** , navigate to your project root or folder where the composer.json file is located in **Command Line** and run this :
`composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg@~0.5`